# RecyclerView shows wrong views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

RecyclerView shows first items after some correct items. And one of incorrect items can change own data several times... It is really strange and i dont know why, in another app i wrote the same code and all works nice. I tried to find the resolve, but did not found nothing what helps. You can see video to understand what is going on.
[video](https://youtu.be/cEsJzGT-4KU)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_car_list, container, false);
mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.car_recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
updateUI();
return view;
}

private class CarHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
View.OnClickListener {

private Car mCar;

public CarHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    mProducerTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.producerCardTextView);
    mModelTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.modelCardTextView);
    mPriceTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceCardTextView);
}

public void bind(Car car) {
    mCar = car;
    mProducerTextView.setText(getString(R.string.producer_params, 
mCar.getProducer()));
    mModelTextView.setText(getString(R.string.model_params, 
mCar.getModel()));
    mPriceTextView.setText(getString(R.string.price_params, 
mCar.getPrice()));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    mListCallBack.onCarSelected(mCar);
}
}

private class CarAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CarHolder> {

private List<Car> mCars;

public CarAdapter(List<Car> cars) {
    mCars = cars;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CarHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_car, viewGroup, false);
    return new CarHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CarHolder carHolder, int i) {
    Car car = mCars.get(i);
    carHolder.bind(car);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCars.size();
}

public void setCars(List<Car> cars) {
    this.mCars = cars;
}
}

public void updateUI(){
List<Car> cars = CarLab.getCarLab(getActivity()).getCars();
if (mAdapter == null) {
    mAdapter = new CarAdapter(cars);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
} else {
    mAdapter.setCars(cars);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be you can try your RecyclerView not to recyle items using:

```
mRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(0,0);
```

in your `onCreate()` method below `mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(...)`;

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you use the field variable `mCar` (which manipulates by all bind events) to update your `viewHoleder`, just simply use the `car` variable you pass to the `bind` to update views.

The other problem with your code is inside `onClick`, again you should not use the field variable `mCar`, instead get the item it needs like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Car car = mCars.get(getAdapterPosition());
    mListCallBack.onCarSelected(car);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it does not help me.