# How to hide only one clicked item title from a horizontal LinearLayoutManager based RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I am using horizontal `LinearLayoutManager` to create a horizontal list on my `RecyclerView` as shown in the picture below
[image: Screenshot 1]

My purpose is to hide the RecyclerView item title when I click on it. But when I click for example on the first item title to hide it, it is successfully hidden but the titles of items at positions 8,15,22,29, etc are also hidden as shown in the picture below.
[image: Picture 2]
[image: Picture 3]

My adapter:

```
public class HomeProduitsPromoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeProduitsPromoAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    
    private List<HomeProduitsPromoInnerItem> dataSet;
    private Context mContext;

    public HomeProduitsPromoAdapter(Context context, List<HomeProduitsPromoInnerItem> listItems) {
        this.dataSet = listItems;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView nomProduit,prixProduit,prixBarre;
        protected ImageView itemImage;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.nomProduit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textGoodsName);
            this.prixProduit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textGoodsPrice);
            this.prixBarre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textGoodsOldPrice);
            this.itemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageGoodsPic);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_home_produits_promo_inner_content, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int i) {

        final HomeProduitsPromoInnerItem singleItem = dataSet.get(i);

        holder.nomProduit.setText(singleItem.getNomProduitWithUnite());
        holder.prixProduit.setText(singleItem.getPrixProduit());
        holder.prixBarre.setText(singleItem.getPrixBarre());
        holder.prixBarre.setPaintFlags(holder.prixBarre.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

        int placeholder=R.drawable.ic_category_def;
        Glide.with(holder.itemView)
                .load(singleItem.getUrlImage())
                .placeholder(placeholder)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(holder.itemImage);

        holder.nomProduit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                holder.nomProduit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }
}
```

My fragment code

```
private HomeProduitsPromoAdapter homeMeilleursProduitsAdapter;

homeMeilleursProduitsAdapter=new HomeProduitsPromoAdapter(getContext(), homeProduitsPromoInnerItems);
home_recyclerview_meilleurs_produits.setAdapter(homeMeilleursProduitsAdapter);
home_recyclerview_meilleurs_produits.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL,false));
```

Comment: try this if it works

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54048779/recyclerview-shows-wrong-views/54049357#54049357

Answer (score 1):

Disabling recycler is not a proper solution here. do follow following steps:

1. Add one boolean flag in `HomeProduitsPromoInnerItem` class. let's say `isShowingTitle`.
2. Now in your adapter's `onBindViewHolder()` method add following condition to  show/hide item title (replace your `holder.nomProduit.setOnClickListener...` line with following):

   ```
   if (singleItem.isShowingTitle) {
       holder.nomProduit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       holder.nomProduit.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) view -> {
           singleItem.isShowingTitle = false;
           holder.nomProduit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       });

   } else {
       holder.nomProduit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       holder.nomProduit.setOnClickListener(null);
   }
   ```

using this, every item's title visibility will be stored in `dataSet` list. and every time when recyclerView redraw the item, you will get updated title visibility.

In your question, i don't see how you going to make title visible. SO i'm not adding that part in answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Include a flag inside your `HomeProduitsPromoInnerItem` data class, that will save the title visible state of the specific item.
2. Add a listener to handle click on the title with a setOnClickListener on your item (seems you already do that).
3. Force a RecyclerView refresh.
4. Handle the visibility of the item/title inside the `onBindViewHolder` based on the flag value.